# bootstrap modal and virtual keyboard in ipad

Tags: javascript, jquery, ipad, bootstrap-modal

I am testing my website in ipad.I have used bootstrap modal.But when my modal pop up is open and I am writing something through my ipad virtual keyboard and then if I click any button in the pop-up without closing the keyboard manually my pop-up also gets closed with the keyboard. Why is this happening?

Please Help.